# How to repeat or stop

Tags: python, repeat

I am trying to make a program that asks a text, then repeats it x many times as you want it. I want it to ask you always when it finishes the earlier text, and if you type "Stop" it will end the program. So far I have done this:

```
text = input("Give a text: ")
times = int(input("Give a number: "))


for i in range(0, times):
        print(text)
```

A example:

```
Give a text: Wadap
Give a number: 3
Wadap 
Wadap
Wadap

Give a text: Hi
Give a number: 2
Hi
Hi

Give a text: Stop
Stopping.
```

Comment: while loop is what you are looking for

Comment: @Prune I think this question has nothing to do with the question you've marked as duplicate. The phrasing of OP is quite confusing though.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: The principle is the same: loop the entire program while/until the user gives a particular input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your existing code into a `while` loop:

```
text = input("Give a text: ")
while text != "Stop": 
    times = int(input("Give a number: "))
    for i in range(0, times):
        print(text)
    text = input("Give a text: ")
print("Stopping")
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd like to wrap everything in `while` cycle.

```
some_condition = True
while some_condition:
    <your code>
```

Here `some_condition` is just a variable that you can control to exit the program.

Comment: I can't fix your indentation on my phone but why is `python` in your code?

Comment: woops, was just formatting mistake by me